# Limit of big O term.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I am trying to proof from the defition of big-O that 
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{O(|x|^2)}{1+O(|x|^4)} = 0. 
$$
It seems not that hard but It can't quite get there. I can only bound the numerator to get something like 
$$
\frac{O(|x|^2)}{1+O(|x|^4)} \leq \frac{C|x|^2}{1+O(|x|^4)}  = \frac{C}{1/|x|^2+O(|x|^2)}
$$
I don't know how to continue from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numerator goes to $0$. The denominator goes to $1$. So...

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. But is it possible to give a formal proof of this using big-O definition?

Comment: There exists a constant $C>0$ such that, for each $\varepsilon>0$, your expression is bounded by
$$
\frac{Cx^2}{1-\varepsilon}
$$
with $x$ sufficiently small. Now choose, e.g., $\varepsilon=1/2$.